# Добавить класс на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Для дива

```
      <div class="right">

      <h2>Новости</h2>

      <div class="news-teaser floatbox">
          <a href="/news/news_3.html" class="preview icaption_left"><img src="images/teaser-news.jpg" alt="teaser-news.jpg, 2,3kB" title="Teaser news" border="0" height="54" width="74"></a>
        <span class="date"> 31 августа 2012</span>  <h3><a href="/news/news_4.html">Реорганизация предприятия</a></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="news-teaser floatbox">
        <a href="/news/news_3.html" class="preview icaption_left"><img src="images/teaser-news.jpg" alt="teaser-news.jpg, 2,3kB" title="Teaser news" border="0" height="54" width="74"></a>
        <span class="date"> 31 августа 2012</span>  <h3><a href="/news/news_4.html">Реорганизация предприятия</a></h3>
      </div>
</div>
```

Пишу такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("div.right div.floatbox:hover").addClass("active");
                });

</script>
```

то есть, к элементу, на который наводится мышка, должен добавляться класс `active`, но скрипт не срабатывает.

Что не так, как это поправить?

Comment: "на который наводится мышка" а в чем это выражается в коде?

Comment: в скрипте указан псевдокласс :hover

Comment: @Heidel - ясно, fail :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('div.right div.floatbox').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
});
```

Перед тем как использовать jquery было-бы чудесно почитать документацию, а еще лучше - выучить JavaScript.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь)))

Answer (score 1):

jQuery так не работает. селекторы в параметрах сделаны похожими на css, но это не css, они, можно сказать, сделаны так для удобства. поэтому нельзя что-то присвоить селектру с псевдоклассом. тут придется вешать класс событием mouseover